# Laravel using find without condition and dynamic where condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I want to query an eloquent method and later paginate. So I have written the code as

```
    $roles = Role::find();
    if (!empty($request->get("globalFilter"))){
        $roles->where('name','LIKE','%' . $request->get("globalFilter"). '%');
    }
    return response()->json($roles->paginate($request->get("perPage")));
```

The above throws the following error

> too few arguments on function builder find

How can I still call `where` and `paginate` in my query above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to pass one value to `find()` method as parameter.So that it will return one record based on given id .If you dont have id and want to fetch first record then you have to use `first()`.
Also you are using paginate to return result ,i think you don't need find() method.

It should be

```
 $roles = Role::query();
    if (!empty($request->get("globalFilter"))){
        $roles->where('name','LIKE','%' . $request->get("globalFilter"). '%');
    }

$result=$roles->find($id);
```

or you can use if condition inside where callback like below

```
$roles = Role::where(function ($query)use($request){
    if(!empty($request->globalFilter)){
        $query->where('name','LIKE','%' . $request->get("globalFilter"). '%');
    }
    
})->find($id);
```

or you can use `when`  to make query simpler

```
$roles = Role::when((!empty($request->globalFilter)),function($query)use($request){

    $query->where('name','LIKE','%' . $request->get("globalFilter"). '%');
})->find($id);
```

**Note:** for `find()` method you have to pass one parameter as `id` or you have to use `first()`.Both return one record.For multiple records you can use `all()` or `get()`

Ref for when clause:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses

Ref for first() and find():https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-a-single-row-column-from-a-table

If you are looking for return all roles where name like then you can do the following

```
 $roles = Role::when((!empty($request->globalFilter)),function($query)use($request){
    
        $query->where('name','LIKE','%' . $request->get("globalFilter"). '%');
    })->paginate($request->get("perPage"));
```